# How citation networks are associated with complex adaptive systems?

Tags: complexity-theory, sna, network-analysis, citations, complex-networks

I have read that citation networks are associated with the complex adaptive networks as they exhibit following characteristics: self-organization, emergence, no-linearity, order/chaos dynamic, and are adaptive to its environment. I want to know exactly which feature of citations exhibits each of these (just a brief overview). 
I also know that citation networks follow power-law and small world properties of complex networks. They also have high clustering coefficient.

Comment: 1) This question is too broad. 2) It has nothing to do with complexity theory.

Answer (score 0):

In citation networks, documents interact in a non-linear fashion, leading to emergent patterns which are difficult to understand simply by considering the individual document. In-degree of the citations follow a power law; a few documents are highly-cited and the majority of documents have low or no citations. There is no centralized control in citation networks. While the behaviour of citations may change, evolve over time, or adapt to its changing environment, the citations and bibliographic coupling are essentially a Complex Adaptive System (CAS).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it depends on what feature you are looking for in the network. In some cases when you try to see the flow or percolation in citation networks you might find non-linearity emerging. Adaptiveness in the network has to deal with optimization of some network feature.